# Where is String.Intern method in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, string, .net-core

I've created new .NET Core console application and can not find string interning methods.

Here's an old doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from the [github issues page of IronLanguages](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/issues/1381) (that had the same problem):

> String.Intern will be added in .NET Standard 2.0, which will also be implemented by .NET Core:
>
> https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/netstandard/ref/mscorlib.cs#L3048

The [github of corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10216) seems to support this: one of the missing function is `System.String.Intern(System.String)` and the issue is tagged as `netstandard2.0`.